# プログレスバーが出力されるときとされないときがある。

Tags: julia, random

計算の途中過程と予定終了時刻を出力するために、Qiitaに書いてあるプロセスバーを表示させるものを参考に以前質問したランダムウォークを走らせてみると、プロセスバーが表示されるときとされないときで別れてなぜか原因がわかりません。常に表示できるようにするにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。[参考にしたサイト](https://qiita.com/bicycle1885/items/6c7cd3d853e00ddfc250)
ちなみにエディタはjupyterです。

Comment: Qiitaの記事へのリンクがあると良いかと。

Answer (score 0):

どうやら、処理が大きすぎて、予定終了時刻を算出するのに時間がかかっているみたいでした。。